# implementation generic stack in c

Tags: c, generics, stack

```
typedef struct Stack_t* Stack;
typedef void* Element;
typedef Element (*CopyFunction)(Element);
typedef void (*FreeFunction)(Element);
```

Can you please explain me the meaning of the third line ?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a similar nature to aid your understanding , typedef of function pointers.

```
typedef int (*intfunctionpointer_t) (int);
```

so what we are saying here is, intfunctionpointer_t is a type of function pointer, where the function has a single parameter of type int, and returns an integer.

suppose you have two functions say,

```
int foo (int);
int bar (int);
```

then,

```
intfunctionpointer_t function = foo;    
function(5);
```

calling function(5), will end up calling foo(5);

You can also extend this , by assigning the same function pointer to another function of the same signature.

```
function = bar;
function(7);
```

Now calling function(7), will end up calling bar(7);

Answer (score 3):

This is a `function pointer` you can address a function to that takes an `Element` and returns an `Element`, like

```
Element ReturnElem(Element el){ } //define function

CopyFunction = ReturnElem;  //assign to function pointer

Element el = ....;
Element el2 =  CopyFunction(el); //call function using function-pointer
```

See [here](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#callconv) for function-pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
typedef Element (*CopyFunction)(Element);
```

defines an alias called `CopyFunction` for a function pointer type, with the function returning an instance of an `Element` and has a single argument of `Element`.

Contrived example:

```
/* Function declaration. */
Element f1(Element e);
Element f2(Element e);

Element e = { /* ... */ };
CopyFunction cf = f1;
cf(e); /* Invokes f1(). */

cf = f2;
cf(e); /* Invokes f2(). */
```

Other example of function pointer use:

- [`qsort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort)
- [`bsearch()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/bsearch)